# Sequence Question

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $lim(x_n)=A$, then $lim(x_1+...+x_n)/n=A$, but the converse is not true. I'm really not sure how to approach this... for the first direction, I started by saying since $(x_n)$ converges, $\forall\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|x_n-A|<\epsilon$, for $n\ge N$ so $|(x_1+...+x_n)/n-A|=|((x_1-A)+...+(x_n-A))/n|$, but i'm not sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks good. Now apply the triangle inequality and take the limit to infinity in the sum on the right. Follow it up by noting that $|x_n - A|$ converges to zero so for each $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $|x_n - A| < \varepsilon$. Divide the sum into one part running from 1 to N and another running from N+1 to infinity. How can you proceed from this point to make this sum of two series smaller than $2\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessity. You absolutely correct. Now, let us call $y_i=x_i-A$. Using the inequality for modulus: $|y_1+y_2+\dots|/n\le|y_1|/n+|y_2|/n+\dots$. What do you know about $|y_i|$? You don't really know much when $i<N$, so let's leave it alone and call their sum $C=|y_1|+\dots+|y_{N-1}|$. For the rest you know that if $i\ge N$ then $|y_i|<\epsilon$. Overall for a given $n$ you have $C/n+\frac{n-N+1}{n}\epsilon$. Can you now conclude that this can be made arbitrary small?

Sufficiency. Consider something like $x_i=(-1)^i$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you, this was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* For fxied $N$, $\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_N}n\to 0$ and $\frac{x_{N+1}+\ldots+x_n}n\approx \frac{n-N}n A$ if all $x_k\approx A$.